# Delete The Selected ID from Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a comment section on my index.php page. (like I have displayed here) I have a delete link that sends you to the delete page. I want to be able to delete that specific ID when it is clicked.
index.php

```
 <div class='commentnest'>
                <p id='id'> ".$row['id']."</p>
                <p id='user'> ".$row['user'].":</p>
                <p id='comment'>".$row['usercomment']." </p>
                <p id='time'>".$row['timestamp']."</p>
                <a href='delete.php?=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>
        </div>
```

delete.php page

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM commenttable WHERE id=id";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

every time I send a specific comment there, it deletes all the comments. I know it's because I'm not stating which ID to select, but i'm having a hard time figuring that out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: read that - http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: `id = id` is true. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/add33/3 First name your `GET` parameter. Then use parameterized query to delete the value.

Comment: you need a GET array for this

Comment: Don't use GET for deletion, use POST.  GET is for, well... getting.

Comment: @AbraCadaver *Alrighty* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All records are deleted because `id=id` will be always true unless id is NULL. You need to properly pass it from your HTML:

```
<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>
```

and then properly use it in the query:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM commenttable WHERE 
  id='".mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST["id"])."'" ;
```

if the id is always an integer, you can write simpler:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM commenttable WHERE 
  id=".(int)$_REQUEST["id"]);
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: mysqli_escape_string() or casting the user input to int removes the possibility of SQL injection. While prepared statements can also protect against SQL injection, this is not the only way to do it.

Comment: Escaping the string, while a good idea, can be defeated. Anyhow - props to you and your running family! You're all faster than I am! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: *All records are deleted because id=id will be always true unless id is NULL* - You are wrong. They are deleted because for every row field id is equal itself

Comment: `create table test.t1(id int, n int);insert into t1 values (1,1), (NULL,2); delete from test.t1 where id = id;select * from test.t1;` - you will see that the second record is still there. It is possible for `id=id` to be false, and it is achieved when `id` is NULL.